# issues with viewWithTag in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am using this method to delete 3 different stack object( A , B ,C) , but sometime delete order changes and it start deleting other stack object , lets say i click on A del button , but it delete B stack button

// for A  stack Deletion
- (IBAction)delWhis:(id)sender {

```
if(j>1)
    {
    j--;

    [[self.view viewWithTag:j] removeFromSuperview];


        {
        NSLog(@" whisky  ration is  %d",width1);
        width1 = width1 +38;


        }


    }
```

}

// for B stack deletion 
- (IBAction)delWhiskkk:(id)sender {

```
if(ji>1)
    {
    ji--;

    [[self.view viewWithTag:ji] removeFromSuperview];


        {
        NSLog(@" whisky  ration is  %d",width1);
        width1 = width1 +38;


        }


    }
```

}

anyidea how to fix this

thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.view viewWithTag:j]
```

The above code returns The Object that Contains Tag As `j` in That Particular UiView.

for example Let Us Suppose `j = 0`.
This will Return **one** View that has a tag of `0`. If Suppose I have a  UILabel, and UITextFeild have the same tags. Only the first in the view array will be removed, not both. So We Must Maintain  Distinct Tags.
By Default any view Tag IS `0`. IT's best to try maintaining Distant Tags It Will Work Fine.

Answer (score 0):

Well i got the ans,  since all my 3 stacks A B C have tag value from 0 to 10 , so  while deleting any of the stack  if tag value matches any of the other Stack ABC then it start del them, so all tag increment counter must be different

thanks